# XSLT Muenchian Grouping to HTML Table

Tags: xml, xslt, muenchian-grouping

Here is my XML:

```
<Tree All="False">
  <Menu Type="Leaf">
    <Label>Menu 1</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 2</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 3</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Break />
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 4</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 5</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 6</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 7</Label>
  </Menu>
  <Break />
  <Menu>
    <Label>Menu 8</Label>
  </Menu>
</Tree>
```

I'm trying to convert the nodes into an HTML table, with `<Break />` node as the separator. The expected HTML output is:

[image]

I'm able to group the nodes by Muenchian method using XSLT 1.0. But now I'm stuck at converting them to HTML table. Here is my current XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="groups" match="Tree*[not(self::Break)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::Break)" />

<xsl:template match="Tree">
  <xsl:variable name="groupings" select="*[not(self::Break)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))[1])]" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$groupings">
    <xsl:sort select="count(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break)))" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:variable name="rows" select="count(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break)))" />
      <xsl:call-template name="GroupTemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="$rows" />
        <xsl:with-param name="groupings" select="$groupings" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="GroupTemplate">
  <xsl:param name="rows" />
  <xsl:param name="groupings" />
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="$groupings">
      <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))" />
      <xsl:for-each select="$group[position() &lt;= $rows]">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
      <br></br>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

My current code is giving me this result, which is incorrect:

> Menu 1 Menu 2 Menu 3
>
> Menu 4 Menu 5 Menu 6 Menu 7
>
> Menu 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've started off correctly, by identifying the group with the maximum number of rows. What you really need to do is an "for 1 to $maxorw" in your template, which you can do in XSLT 2.0, but not 1.0 easily. What you could do though is that instead of passing in the value of the max rows, pass in the group with the max rows instead, and select from that to start with. The 'position' then gives you the "1 to 4" you need.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" />
<xsl:key name="groups" match="Tree/*[not(self::Break)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::Break)" />

<xsl:template match="Tree">
  <xsl:variable name="groupings" select="*[not(self::Break)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))[1])]" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$groupings">
    <xsl:sort select="count(key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break)))" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:variable name="maxRows" select="key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))" />
      <xsl:call-template name="GroupTemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="maxRows" select="$maxRows" />
        <xsl:with-param name="groupings" select="$groupings" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="GroupTemplate">
  <xsl:param name="maxRows" />
  <xsl:param name="groupings" />
  <table>
    <xsl:for-each select="$maxRows">
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$groupings">
          <xsl:variable name="group" select="key('groups', count(preceding-sibling::Break))" />
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($group[position() = $position])" />
          </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: as always, thank you @Tim C for the fast response. this worked for me.

Comment: follow up question, do you know how to get the name of the node that matched? For the above example, I want to have **Menu** as result cos the node is contained inside a `<Menu>.. </Menu>`. I tried something like `$group[position() = $position][name()]` and `$group[position() = $position]/name()` but neither gives the expected output. I thought name() or local-name() would work.

Comment: Ah I got it, @Tim C. This line worked: `name($group[position() = $position])`

Comment: That's right, although `$group[position() = $position]/name()` would work in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Hello @Tim C, I have another query and I hope you don't mind. I thought I'd ask you directly here instead of creating a new question. Please see my updated XML. I want to make some adjustment in `<xsl:key name="groups" match="Tree*[not(self::Break)]" />`, such that if `Tree/@All` attribute is set as True, all `<Menu>` nodes will be included in the grouping. If it is False, I will exclude those Menu with `@Type` attribute. In the above XML sample, Menu 1 should be excluded from the grouping.

Comment: I think you need to adjust the key to `<xsl:key name="groups" match="Tree/*[not(self::Break)][not(@Type) or /Tree/@All = 'True']" use="count(preceding-sibling::Break)" />`